# Jquery drop down and input form function not quite working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this awesome piece of code that i am trying to put into a form for data population but i am still trying to get it working, i can see that the function itself is working but there is something wrong still that i just can't work out. when i did get it functional it was echo'ing the internal code and i can't seem to populate the data from the sql either. It looks mostly good but there is just 1 thing missing from it im sure.

can anyone see what could be wrong?

```
 <?
include 'conn.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $.get( "myfunctions/get_records_for_select.php", function( data ) {
    //Look we will change the HTML content for our select-box on success
    $( "#myselectbox" ).html( data );
  });

  $( "#myselectbox" ).change(function() {

    $.post( "myfunctions/get_records_by_id.php", { selectedId: $(this).val() })
    .done(function( data ) {
      $( "#myinputbox" ).val( data );
    });
 });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select id="myselectbox">
    <option>Select</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="myinputbox">
</body>
</html>




<?
// your get_records_for_select.php file

include '../conn.php';

$yourSql = "SELECT * FROM `intrusion`";
$results = run_sql($yourSql);
$html = "<option></option>";
foreach($results as $record){
$html .= "<option value=" . $record['SAPCode'] . "></option>";
}

echo $html;exit;
?>



<?

include '.../conn.php';

// your get_records_by_id.php file
$post_data = $_POST['SAPCode'];
$yourSql = "select * FROM intrusion WHERE id=".$post_data;
$results = run_sql($yourSql);
$row = $results->row();
echo $row['SAPCode'];exit;
?>
```

// updated index.php form with sql populated data that is working but still // no change functions ID
    "; 
    echo "";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) 
    {
    echo "".$row['SAPCode'].""; 
    }
    echo "";
    ?>

Comment: What are you trying to do, and what is the problem?

Comment: i am trying to use a sql populated drop down list that onchange pulls data through jquery from sql and places it in the input form which then i start the next stage of posting the data to PDF for a completed task.

The problem is that the select form does not seem to be functional at this stage and unable to populate which then is not triggering the onchange function of jquery.

Comment: what is the purpose of 'SAPCode' in get_records_by_id.php while you are passing selectedId in your post request..
Also what is response in the console to this ajax request..?

Comment: SAPCode is just a field of SQL so when the dropdown sql populated field is selected then the related data to that item will be in the form.

Comment: Thats what I am saying.. you are passing selectedId from your $.post and you are looking for key SAPCode in the post data.. it will result in an undefined index..

Comment: Okay.. what is the response in the browser's console when you select an item in your dropdown.

Comment: Take your javascripts to the bottom of the file before </body> tag..

Comment: there is no console items what so ever, i am using firefox developers edition. i can't seem to get 1 single error code to work from this is just getting bs. i am almost at the point where i will just pay someone to finish this section.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write-

```
`<select id="myselectbox" onchange="FunctionName()">
    <option>Select</option>
</select>
function FunctionName(){
$.post( "myfunctions/get_records_by_id.php", { selectedId: $(this).val() })
    .done(function( data ) {
      $( "#myinputbox" ).val( data );
    });
}`
```

You are adding change event onready but loading data from ajax, so it's not getting the current content of select.

Comment: i tried your suggestion but still no change, i am still not getting a list in the drop down. i am going to look at that next and if i can get a list happening the jq function mite work. working progress....

Comment: In my first post i have updated the dropdown with some other code i have been working on that will populate the drop down with sql data but still can't activate the Jq function

Comment: You mean that function is not being called on onchange?

Comment: Yes, i select an item from the drop down that is populated by SQL data and nothing happens with the function ID.